# Wrong PDF bookmark mapping issue with redefined appendices or chapters

Tags: appendices, bookmarks

I am using the package [`utdiss2.sty`](http://pastebin.com/X9n0RUkc) in a paper. When I use the package like this example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{utdiss2}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{appendix}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Ch1}
\lipsum
\chapter{Ch2} 
\lipsum

%\bookmarksetupnext{level=part}
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Hello}
\lipsum
\chapter{World}
\lipsum
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Eveything's OK, but the PDF does not have a correct matching in bookmark. 
The first appendix matches to Chapter 1, not the first appendix.

[image]

I looked into the appendices environment in the `utdiss2.sty` package and commented out `\setcounter{chapter}{0}`.

```
\def\appendices{\clearpage
    \typeout{Appendices.}
    \short@page \setcounter{regular@short}{1}   % <- 9/13/96 (MAL)
        \markboth{}{}\pagestyle{myheadings} % <- The appendices must
        \thispagestyle{plain}           % <- be numbered.
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \centerline{\large\bf Appendices}
    \vspace*{\fill}

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}  % <-

    \setcounter{chapter}{0} % <---
    \setcounter{section}{0} 
    \def\@chapapp{\appendixname}
    \chap@or@app=2
    \def\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}}
```

Now, the bookmark works fine, but the numbering is wrong; Appendix C and D instead of Appendix A and B.

Without the `utdiss2.sty` package, there is no problem, so there is something changed in this package.

[image]

What might be wrong? What might be causing this kind of issue (wrong bookmark mapping) when redefining appendices or chapters?

Comment: Try to load `utdiss2` **before** `hyperref` (which should be loaded last anyway in 99.9% of all cases.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: I tried but I have the same results.

Comment: Actually, I don't see what the fix '%\setcounter{chapter}{0}` does really solve in your bookmark issue? What is the issue? Do you want to have individual appendix chapters grouped below `Appendices`, i.e. indented in the bookmarks? Or is the hyperlink wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is most likely the well-known problem:

`\setcounter{chapter}{0}` leads to wrong `hyperref` anchors, since counter values are used to build such anchors.

One solution is to provide another `\theHchapter` setup, say

```
\renewcommand{\theHchapter}{\appendixname.\thechapter}
```

This will write names like

```
   \@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{Appendix A.\hspace  *{1em}Hello}{10}{chapter.Appendix.A}}
```

to the `.aux` file, given correct hyperlinks like `chapter.Appendix.A` and not `chapter.1` again, which is there already for the real first chapter.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{utdiss2}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\xapptocmd{\appendices}{%
  \renewcommand{\theHchapter}{\appendixname.\thechapter}
}{}{}

\usepackage{bookmark}



\begin{document}
\chapter{Ch1}
\lipsum
\chapter{Ch2} 
\lipsum

\bookmarksetupnext{level=part}


\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Hello}
\lipsum
\chapter{World}
\lipsum
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]